# $_session not working with session_start(); called

Tags: php, session

$_Session have worked on my website before, but now it is not working.
This is where i call it.

```
<?php session_start();

echo $_SESSION['a']; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Ajouter Liste</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
```

This is where i set the session variable, i can't make it work.

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include 'connect.php';

$pseudo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
$mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$password = sha1($password);

$pseudo1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo1']);
$password1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password1']);
$password1 = sha1($password1);
$action = $_POST['action'];

if ($action == "register")
{
$rep = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO login (pseudo, mail, password) VALUES(:pseudo, :mail, :password)');
$rep->execute(array(

    'pseudo' => $pseudo,
    'mail' => $mail,
    'password' => $password));
}

if ($action == "login")
{
$rep = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM login WHERE pseudo = :pseudo AND password = :password');
$rep->execute(array(

    'pseudo' => $pseudo1,
    'password' => $password1));
$req = $rep->fetch();
if (isset($req['pseudo']))
{
$arr = array('response' => 'gg');

echo json_encode($arr);

$_SESSION['a'] = "test";

}
else
{
$arr = array('response' => 'fail');

echo json_encode($arr);
}

}
 ?>
```

The code above is running perfectly fine but i can get $_SESSION['a'] when i go to the first page.

[phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyjOJ.png)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try to assign a variable to the session; then echo the variable? `$var = $_SESSION["HelloWord"];`

Comment: '$_SESSION['a'] = "test";
echo $_SESSION['a'];' returns "test"

Comment: at the top of your page put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then clear all the error.log files in your ftp file folder. Then run the script, then pull the error from the ftp directory and paste that error here.

Comment: no error.log file is returned, i added error_reporting(E_ALL); on both of the page.

Comment: hrmm... Doesnt display in any folder? typically where ever the file is located is where it'll display at. if the error is coming from that "file".

Comment: You sure it enters `if (isset($req['pseudo']))`? If *no* errors are returned, and nothing is displayed when you think the session is set, something isn't adding up (you're either not checking for errors or you're missing something). What is the output of `echo json_encode($arr);`, for example? You can also do `echo isset($_SESSION['a']) ? $_SESSION['a'] : "Session not set";`, see if it's actually set or not.